# Playwright - Fake canvas, audio and font-families

Tags: node.js, escaping, fingerprint, playwright

I'm trying to make my playwright browser profile to be unique with different fingerprints.
I believe the fingerprints are generated base on lots of browser data, included canvas, audio and font-families.

So I want to set above data values randomly whenever I started a playwright browser, please let me know if you worked on the same case before, and how it looks like in the code lines (nodejs)

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is through loading extensions. There are already chrome extensions present which alter your fingerprints and playwright allows you to [load](https://playwright.dev/docs/chrome-extensions) extensions during launch. The only drawback is that you would not be able to use headless mode if you want to use extensions.

Comment: Does anyone have a working solution for this, but in headless mode?